# Replace String Value Digits based on their count in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

```
df:
    Col_A        Month
0 March 2020      Mar
1 March 20        Mar
2 Ebg 2020        Mar
3 17 GOFE         Mar
4 APR 17          Mar
5 16 HGN          Nov
6 2015 ref        May
7 18Jun           Jul
```

How to replace digit from a string variable in pandas dataframe,
for Example i need to replace digits in Col_A with 2019 or 19.
if digit count or length in col_A is 4 then 2019 else 19.

Output:

```
    Col_A        Month
0 March 2019      Mar
1 March 19        Mar
2 Ebg 2019        Mar
3 19 GOFE         Mar
4 APR 19          Mar
5 19 HGN          Nov
6 2019 ref        May
7 19Jun           Jul
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is how you can use `re`:

```
import pandas as pd
from re import sub, findall

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df['Col_A'] = [sub('\d\d\d\d','2019',m)
               if findall('\d\d\d\d',m)
               else sub('\d\d','19',m)
               for m in df['Col_A']]
```

---

UPDATE: Another way:

```
import pandas as pd
from re import sub, findall

df = pd.DataFrame(...)

df['Col_A'] = df.Col_A.map(lambda m: sub('[0-9]{4}','2019',m)
                           if findall('[0-9]{4}',m)
                           else sub('[0-9]{2}','19',m))
```

---

---

UPDATE: cs95 gave this short solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(...)

df['Col_A'] = df['Col_A'].str.replace('\d{2}(?!\d)', '19')
```

Comment: This seems quite ugly, can you do better? Generally we don't like iterating over DataFrames, you will need to learn vectorized routines if you want to succeed at pandas. Not the downvoter.

Comment: Also, you're evaluating up to three different regular expressions (which is kind of inefficient) to achieve what Cary Swoveland did in one.

Comment: Better but still has room for improvement. Pandas supports regular expressions with string functions: `df['Col_A'].str.replace('\d{2}(?!\d)', '19')` is how I would do this. Rome was not built in a day, I suggest observing other answers in the tag before writing your own.

Answer (score 2):

As the examples in the question contained strings of two and four strings I have assumed that the last two digits of strings of four digits are to be replaced with `"19"` and strings  of two digits are to be replaced with `"19"`.

The following regular expression can be used with `re.sub` to make those replacements.

```
r'(?<!\d)(?=\d{2}(?!\d))\d{2}|(?<=(?<!\d)\d{2})\d{2}(?!\d)'
```

The strings:

```
1 2 GOFE          Mar
2 23 GOFE         Mar
3 567 GOFE        Mar
4 5678 GOFE       Mar
5 3456789 GOFE    Mar
```

respectively become:

```
1 2 GOFE          Mar
2 19 GOFE         Mar
3 567 GOFE        Mar
4 5619 GOFE       Mar
5 34567 GOFE      Mar
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T1wj7D/3/)|[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/WEsMg46N)

Python's regex engine performs the following operatons.

```
(?<!\d)   : use negative lookbehind to assert previous
            character is not a digit
(?=       : begin positive lookahead
  \d{2}   : match 2 digits
  (?!\d)  : use negative lookahead to assert next
            character is not a digit 
)         : end non-capture group
\d{2}     : match 2 digits
|         : or
(?<=      : begin positive lookbehind
  (?<!\d) : use negative lookbehind to assert previous
            character is not a digit
  \d{2}   : match 2 digits
)         : end positive lookbehind
\d{2}     : match 2 digits
(?!\d)    : use negative lookahead to assert next
            character is not a digit
```